# Android SDK VideoView - How to buffer second video after first video finished buffering while first video is still played

Tags: android, android-videoview, buffering

I have got this code, which works great for playing one video from http:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private VideoView mVideoView;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Toast.makeText(this,"Loading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
         mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://some_url/movie1.mp4"));
         mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
         mVideoView.requestFocus();
         mVideoView.start();
       }
}
```

What I need to do is to play two or three different videos in a row, but without (or with as small as possible) gap between them.

I thought about checking current video buffer state and when it hits 100%, start in background buffering another video (video one is still playing in foreground). After video one stops playing I would like to i.e. switch instances or buffers and start playing video two.

Is it possible, and if it is can anyone give me a hint about how to code it?

Thanks